# How to use VSProlog in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, prolog, vsprolog

I have installed the VSProlog extension in my Visual Studio 2015, from here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/50f0f293-bcb5-4f95-a9d0-afff92306973

Going to Tools>Extensions and updates I can see the extension installed, and it's enabled. Everything seems fine.

But trying to create a simple prolog .pl or .ari file, in File>New project... I can create C#, Visual Basic files, ASP, Python... but nothing appears related to Prolog.

How can I create a Prolog File in my Visual Studio?

Comment: From what I can tell of the description of the tool at the link you gave: *It enables syntax coloring and the award winning "Go to Definition" command.*. I don't see anything that says it adds a Prolog project to the `File > New project...` menu.

Comment: Ok, but if I open a .pl file with Visual Studio, it appears just like notepad, without any coloring or command... I think I have to indicate VS that it should treat that file like a Prolog file. I don't know how.

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the file to end in `.ari` instead of `.pl`? The example at the link you gave uses `.ari` extension. If that doesn't do it, you might want to contact the author of the tool since it's a 3rd party GPL developed tool.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the extension.

As stated before, [VSProlog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sebastiangomez.VSProlog) is not a template extension. It just enables syntax coloring for prolog files defined as `*.ari` and `*.pl`.
Opening a `.pl` file with Visual Studio and the extension installed (of course) should be enough.

Feel free to file an issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/sebagomez/vsprolog)